# How to target div's x coordinates through if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, statements

How would you target the X coordinates of a div when using an if statement?

What I'm trying to do is to get a div to animate across the screen but I only want it to move when certain x coordinates are met, hence why the if/else statements.

For example;

```
var firstXPos = -20px;
var secondXPos = -40px;
var thridXPos = -60px;

if (div's x pos?? == firstXPos){
$("#id").animate({"left" : secondXPos}, "slow");
} else (div's x pos?? == secondXPos?){
$("#id").animate({"left" : thridXPos}, "slow");
}
```

So how would write the code so that it can target the divs current x postion so that the if / else statements can be met?

Comment: `if($('div').position().left == firstXPos)`

Comment: .position() does not append px to the returned value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following code to check an item's visibility using x and y coordinates

```
isVisible: function (node, doc, x, y) {
    var el = doc.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    if (node === el) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

so in your if statement you could use the above function to check to see if it is in that position